# META DATA Comparison between TWO ORGS

Tags: metadata

Are there any app exchange apps/tools which we can use to compare the meta data between two orgs

Answer (score 0):

Yes Copado Deployer - Org Diff
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B3dgGEAR

Org Diff documentation
http://www.copa.do/cms/documentation#orgDifferences

Comment: I like Flosum. You can also use for org comparison and complete application lifecycle management.